# English word for camel's walk

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

I need to know the English word for a camel's walk. Like Horse runs, Bird flies, so Camel ?
And what to call a female camel also ?

Comment: **Run** is not the word for a horse's walk.  **Walk** is the word.

Comment: Note that horses walk, run (gallop), and also [trot](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trot), [canter](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/canter), and, apparently, [lope](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lope).

Comment: If you're just looking for a new word, I like "plods" for a camel. It kind of goes nicely with their big, flat feet - and it's also what you do in sand. (Often: "plod along".)

Comment: @HotLicks Don’t forget _tölt_, _rack_, _fox trot_, _revaal_, various _pasos_, _huachano_, and probably several hundred more.

Answer (score 3):

A camel walks or gallops.

[This website has plenty of information and facts on camels](http://gittaohan.tripod.com/id4.html), like

> Speed: Walking speed is 3 miles per hour (m.p.h.). A camel caravan would normally travel 25 miles a day. A racing camel can reach 12 m.p.h. at a gallop for short distances. This speed was used by Arab warriors in attacking an enemy.

A female camel is a cow.

Comment: Would that make a male cow a camel? ;)

Comment: I've never read so much bull in my life...

Answer (score 3):

Informally, camels walk and run just like other four footed creatures. This is 'walk' and 'run' are the verbs to use for slow and fast travel.

But if you're [talking technically about gait](http://superbeefy.com/why-do-giraffes-and-camels-walk-with-a-pacing-gait-and-what-is-the-biomechanical-reason-for-it/) (link gives some biological explanation too), the patterns of leg movement at various speeds, the labels for these gaits are similar to that for horses.

Like horses, there is the walking gait, RH RF  LH LF  RH RF LH LF ... but for camels a little bit of extra time between RF and LH, and LF and RH.

A little faster and camels 'pace' instead of 'trot' (horses usually trot but some pace), where instead of opposite corners that horses usually do in pacing, camels move one side together RH+RF  LH+LF  RH+RF  LH+LF ...

A little faster and horses 'canter'. I don't think camels canter.

But fastest and both camels and horses 'gallop', RF+LF   RH+LH   RF+LF   RH+LH...

So if you're a camel trader, you can use walk, pace, and gallop as they are meant, but if you just want to describe a camel going, walking and running are fine

Comment: A beautiful moment of linguistic-ethology inter-disciplinarity